# Is it possible to rotate the controls from a video?

Tags: html, video, controls

I was wondering if it was possible to rotate the controls with the video.
This is my code:

html:

```
<div id="personalvideo">
    <video width="710" height="400" controls>
    <source src="MOV_0007.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
    <object data="MOV_0007.mp4" width="870" height="400">
    <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240">
    </object> 

    </video>
</div>
```

css:

```
#personalvideo
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
    width : 870px;
    margin-left: 315px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Comment: If you have the images in a seperate folder. But with what you provided us i dont think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M sure you can achieve that by Building Custom Controls HTML 5 Videos.

here is link where u can know on how to do it-

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos